# What is the best way to send data from multiple Threads back to the Main Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a mainthread and i do create another n-threads. Each of the n-threads is populating a `List<String>`. When all threads are finished, they are joined, and i would like to have all those n-threads List in a `List<List<String>>` BUT in the mainthread. The mainthread should be able to operate on that `List<List<String>>`. Each of the n-threads contributed a `List<String>`.

I have c# .NET 3.5 and i would like to avoid a `static List<List<String>>`

```
            Thread t = new Thread(someObjectForThreading.goPopulateList);
            list_threads.Add(t);
            list_threads.last().start()
```

all those threads in list_threads go on and populate their List and when they are finished i would like to have something like

```
 //this = mainThread
 this.doSomethingWith(List<List<String>>)
```

Edit: **Hmmm is there no a "standard concept" how to solve such a task?** Many threads operating on a list and when all joined, the mainthread can proceed with operating on the list.

Edit2: **the `List<List<String>> listOfLists` must not be static.** It can be `public or private`. First i need the n-threads to operate (and lock) the listOfLists, insert their List and after all n-threads are done inserting their lists, i would join the threads and the mainthread could proceed with businesslogic and operate on the `listOfLists`

i think i will reRead some parts of http://www.albahari.com/threading/ report back

Comment: Any reason for using Threads instead of Tasks or PLINQ ?

Comment: the threads are making parallel webrequests and wait for response

Comment: Use BeginGetResponse instead of GetResponse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation using wait handles (in the case ManualResetEvent) to allow each worker thread to signal the main thread that it's done with its work. I hope this is somewhat self explanatory:

```
private List<List<string>> _listOfLists;

public void CreateListOfLists()
{
    var waitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>();

    foreach (int count in Enumerable.Range(1, 5))
    {
        var t = new Thread(CreateListOfStringWorker);
        var handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        t.Start(handle);
        waitHandles.Add(handle);
    }

    // wait for all threads to complete by calling Set()
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());

    // do something with _listOfLists
    // ...
}

public void CreateListOfStringWorker(object state)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    lock (_listOfLists)
    {
        _listOfLists.Add(list);
    }

    list.Add("foo");
    list.Add("bar");

    ((ManualResetEvent) state).Set(); // i'm done
}
```

Note how I'm only locking while I add each thread's List to the main list of lists. There is no need to lock the main list for each add, as each thread has its own List. Make sense?

**Edit:**

The point of using the waithandle is to wait for each thread to complete before working on your list of lists. If you don't wait, then you run the risk of trying to enumerate one of the List instances while the worker is still adding strings to it. This will cause an InvalidOperationException to be thrown, and your thread(s) will die. You cannot enumerate a collection and simultaneously modify it.

Comment: Why not do _listOfLists.Add(list) as the first step of the CreateListOfLists() foreach and just pass the worker the single list it will modify? It would mean the new worker thread can run to completion without pause.

Comment: i have not used WaitHandle, so i would have to read a bit about it. Any performance issues?

Comment: @ErnieL Because I wanted to keep the example simple and demonstrative of basic technique. I could have passed the list, sure, but then I have two things to pass: the waithandle and the list. This would mean I'd need another class/struct/tuple to pass as the thread state and then cast/retrieve from the worker. Alternatively I could use closures, but again, this is masking the basic demonstration of threads and thread primitives.

Comment: @Gero there is no performance issue per-se, unless you actually don't want to wait for all workers to complete. IF you don't wait for each thread to complete, then you run the risk of trying to enumerate one of the List<string> instances while the worker is still adding strings to it. This will cause an invalidoperationexception to be throw, and your thread(s) will die.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making the `static List<List<String>>` make a local `List<List<String>>` and pass it to the Object the thread will be running. Of course, you'll need to wrap the `List` in a synchronous wrapper since it's being accessed by multiple threads.

```
List<List<String>> list = ArrayList.synchronized(new ArrayList<List<String>>());

// later
SomeObject o = new SomeObjectForThreading(list);
Thread t = new Thread(o.goPopulateList);
list_threads.Add(t);
list_threads.last().start();

// even later
this.doSomethingWith(list);
```

In `o.goPopulateList`, you might have

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.add(random text);
temp.add(other random text);
this.list.add(temp); // this.list was passed in at construct time
```

Comment: i am already locking(List<List<String>>) and everything works fine as long it is static. Ofcourse, because the mainthread can access it. but when i change static with public, mainthread has 0 elements

Comment: The problem with making it `static` is that then ANY thing can access it. By making it local, nothing else can mess with your data.

Comment: ok, i understand. just give the List<List<String>> as argument with each thread and all threads work on the same List<List<String>>. But this one ArrayList.Synchronized(new ArrayList<List<String>>()); generates an error: The non-generic type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: Not being a C# guy I can't entirely diagnose that issue, or I would. It's probably something simple, perhaps just moving the creation of the list to the line before the sync call, and just `List<List<String>> list = ArrayList.synchronized(tempList)` might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would provide each thread with a call-back method that updates the list in the main thread, protected with a `lock` statement.

Edit:

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> listOfStuff = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() => { new Worker(new AppendToListDelegate(AppendToList)).DoWork(); });
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            threads.Add(thread);
        }
        threads.ForEach(n => n.Start());
        threads.ForEach(n => n.Join());
        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + listOfStuff.Count());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void AppendToList(string arg)
    {
        lock (listOfStuff)
        {
            listOfStuff.Add(arg);
        }
    }
}

public delegate void AppendToListDelegate(string arg);
class Worker
{
    AppendToListDelegate Appender;

    public Worker(AppendToListDelegate appenderArg)
    {
        Appender = appenderArg;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            Appender(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "." + j.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i also thought that goPopulateList() would just return a List<String> but how to implement that?

Comment: Thx for the sample code, but you used STATIC List<String> listOfStuff. I have done the same you did, but now i have to AVOID using static on the list. it has to be a public or private List where threads can operate and in the end the mainthread can operate on the same list.

Comment: List<List<String>> listOfLists would belong to the mainthread. List<String> list would belong to the threads where every thread would make its own list and that list gets inserted into listOfLists.

Comment: I used static because this is a console app and Main is static.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void someObjectForThreading.goPopulateList()
{
    Do threaded stuff...
    populate threaded list..

    All done..
    for (List list in myThreadedList)
    {
        myMainList.Add(list);
    }
}
```